# Missing php.ini after apt-get install php5

Tags: apt, php, grep, find, ls

I just installed php5 as root via `apt-get install php5`, and for whatever reason I can't find my `php.ini` file.

Running `locate php.ini` or `ls /etc/ | grep php.ini` both yield no results.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo updatedb` in your terminal and try `locate php.ini`.

Or you can find php.ini under `/etc/php5/apache2` or `/etc/php5/cli/`.